# Create association between nodes if one doesnt exist using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say there are 2 labels P and M. M has nodes with names M1,M2,M3..M10. I need to associate 50 nodes of P with each Node of M. Also no node of label P should have 2 association with node of M.

This is the cypher query I could come up with, but doesn't seem to work.

```
MATCH (u:P), (r:M{Name:'M1'}),(s:M) 
where not (s)-[:OWNS]->(u) 
with u limit 50 
CREATE (r)-[:OWNS]->(u);
```

This way I would run for all 10 nodes of M. Any help in correcting the query is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any existing :OWNS relationships between :P and :M nodes, or is this query going to be the first to make those kinds of relationships?

Comment: This is the first relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
MATCH (u:P), (r:M{Name:'M1'}),(s:M) 
where not (s)-[:OWNS]->(u) 
with u,r limit 50 
CREATE (r)-[:OWNS]->(u);
```

Thanks for Thomas for mentioning limit on u and r.

Answer (score 5):

You can utilize apoc.periodic.* library for batching. More info in [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/)

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
MATCH (u:P), (r:M{Name:'M1'}),(s:M) where not (s)-[:OWNS]->(u) 
with u,r limit {limit}
CREATE (r)-[:OWNS]->(u)
RETURN count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

If there will always be just one `(r)-[:OWNS]->(u)` relationship, I would change my first match to include

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
MATCH (u:P), (r:M{Name:'M1'}),(s:M) where not (s)-[:OWNS]->(u) and not (r)-[:OWNS]->(u)
with u,r limit {limit}
CREATE (r)-[:OWNS]->(u)
RETURN count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

So there is no way the procedure will fall into a loop

Answer (score 4):

This query should be a fast and easy-to-understand. It is fast because it avoids [Cartesian products](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/cross-product-cypher-queries-will-not-perform-well/):

```
MATCH (u:P)
WHERE not (:M)-[:OWNS]->(u) 
WITH u LIMIT 50
MATCH (r:M {Name:'M1'})
CREATE (r)-[:OWNS]->(u);
```

It first matches 50 unowned `P` nodes. It then finds the `M` node that is supposed to be the "owner", and creates an `OWNS` relationship between it and each of the 50 `P` nodes.

To make this query even faster, you can first create an index on `:M(Name)` so that the owning `M` node can be found quickly (without scanning all `M` nodes):

```
CREATE INDEX ON :M(Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to connect all 10 nodes :M in one query

```
MATCH (m:M)
WITH collect(m) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
MATCH (p:P) where not ()-[:OWNS]->(p)
WITH node,p limit 50
CREATE (node)-[:OWNS]->(p)
```

Although I am not really sure if we need to collect and unwind, could just simplify it to:

```
MATCH (m:M)
MATCH (p:P) where not ()-[:OWNS]->(p)
WITH m,p limit 50
CREATE (node)-[:OWNS]->(p)
```